# QtGStreamer compile-time error in header due to C++11 standard?

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, gstreamer

I am trying to use QtGStreamer with MS Visual Studio 2015's C++ compiler, which defaults to the C++11 standard (more or less).

The header refpointer.h contains the following:

```cpp
template <class T, class X>
struct RefPointerEqualityCheck<T, X*>
{
    static inline bool check(const RefPointer<T> & self, X* const & other)
    {
        return self.m_class ? self.m_class->m_object == other : !other;
    }
};
```

... and later in refpointer.h we have the following:

```cpp
template <class T>
template <class X>
bool RefPointer<T>::operator==(const X & other) const
{
    return Private::RefPointerEqualityCheck<T, X>::check(*this, other);
}

template <class T>
template <class X>
bool RefPointer<T>::operator!=(const X & other) const
{
    return !Private::RefPointerEqualityCheck<T, X>::check(*this, other);
}
```

Someone else encountered the error message I'm getting  [here](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/problem-with-qglib-in-qtgstreamer-td4663095.html):

```
qt5gstreamer\qglib\refpointer.h(280): error C2039: 'check': is not a member of 'QGlib::Private::RefPointerEqualityCheck<T,X>'
        with
        [
            T=QGst::BufferList,
            X=int
        ]
```

One of the main contributors to QtGStreamer replied as follows:

> Hm, looks like the code needs some additions to support C++11's 
>   nullptr. Try removing any compiler flags that enable C++11 
>   functionality (including QTGSTREAMER_FLAGS if you are using cmake) and 
>   see what happens. Also, it would be nice if you open a bug report 
>   about this.

Two things:

(1) I would like to avoid dropping C++11 standards support if it's possible to fix the header (and maybe submit a patch); and

(2) I'm not even sure MSVC++15 has an *option* to go back to an earlier standard version (I couldn't easily find it upon googling).

Contrary to what the compiler message says, it would appear to the untrained eye that `check` is *indeed* defined as a member of `QGlib::Private::RefPointerEqualityCheck` as you can see [here](https://github.com/GStreamer/qt-gstreamer/blob/master/src/QGlib/refpointer.h#L58) in the QtGStreamer sources (that version of the header is identical to what I'm using on my system.)

**Q:** Given the above, is there something wrong with **my** code; something that can be contributed to QtGstreamer to fix the problem; or am I just better off compiling for an earlier version of the C++ standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, my compiler does not point me to the actual *origin* of the problem I encountered. The template parameters of the RefPointer equality check are a *huge* hint.

I encountered this because I was comparing `RefPointer`s to the constant `NULL`, which is `#define`d to `0` (compiled into an `int`).

Thus, when doing something like:

```
BufferListPtr buf; //An instance of RefPointer
//I thought that BufferListPtr was equivalent to `QGst::Buffer*` but apparently it has some overloaded operators, which is the source of our problem!
if(buf == NULL) //Compile-time error!
```

the compiler attempts to invoke `RefPointer`'s `operator==` function, but finds that it isn't applicable to the `X` parameter of `int` (it only allows you to pass in **pointers** (`X*`) or other `RefPointer`s.)

So you have to go through your QtGstreamer code and find all the times where you compared a `RefPointer` instance to `NULL` with `==` or `!=`, and fix them as follows:

```
if(ptr.isNull())
```

The thing to keep in mind is that **all RefPointer instances are *values*, not *pointers***. If you're coming from the Visual C++ world (like I am), and you expect, say, `LPCSTR` to be a simple macro adding a `*` to `CSTR`, don't get that mixed up with what the `Ptr` classes and `RefPointer` do in QtGstreamer! Declaring a `RefPointer` (e.g., `ElementPtr`) actually allocates an instance of the class **on the stack** immediately, so comparing it to NULL makes no sense.

But you can call `isNull()` on it to see if it's NULL or not, because the class will always be initialized if you allocate it on the stack and you're not doing something weird like declaring an `ElementPtr*`.

In conclusion, `RefPointer` and all subclasses of it, including QtGstreamer object types that end in `Ptr`, are just a class that *encapsulates* a pointer to the raw C type, so you have to treat them as a value rather than a pointer.

Comment: This is a main reason you should replace any check against `NULL` with `nullptr`.  That would have brought you right to the error.  The only time you should be checking if something is null is a pointer type.  Even though `RefPointer` wraps a pointer it is not a pointer type.  A pointer type is `T*` like `int*`, `char*`, or `RefPointer*`.

Comment: Yeah, I eventually figured out that fact about `RefPointer` (that it's not a pointer type) as written in the answer. Thanks for the tip about `nullptr`; I'll be sure to use that in the future. It's weird how the semantics of `RefPointer` are *often* similar to an actual pointer, but various "gotchas" don't work. For instance, to call a function on the wrapped raw type, you have to use `->` (there's an overloaded operator for that, too). Interesting...